# restrict execution of a class using a variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate, logic

I have multiple environments like dev, sit, uat. In dev there is no SSL cert configuration but in sit and uat there is a cert configuration. In my code there is SSL related class is there, that class is declared with `@Configuration`. In sit and uat this code will work as is because there is ssl cert configuration is there in both environments. But when it comes to dev environment no SSL cert confguration hence it will throw some errors. Here I want to restrict using a variable. using that variable I want to execute the SSL class.

My Configuration class looks like below.

```
@Configuration
public class SSLConfig {


    @Value("${abc.xyz.keystore.credentials.file}")
    private String keyStoreFile; 
    ....
 
}
```

If I directly execute this class in dev env it will throw cannot able to find `abc.services.keystore.credentials.file-data` error. Hence I want to restrict using a variable.

Comment: Hello, your expected behaviour could be like `keyStoreFile` is null if `abc.services.keystore.credentials.file-data` has not been defined in your application properties file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@Value("${abc.services.keystore.credentials.file-data:}") 
private String keyStoreFile;
```

Which will avoid above error and assign "" if not defined e.g. your dev env. You can perform an empty check on the variable keyStoreFile to define a noop SSL check which will not actually check for SSL.